# Is $\Bbb Q$ a Borel set?

Tags: measure-theory

Is a Borel set $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

I need an explanation.
I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ countable union of singleton sets, but I don`t know is singleton sets are Borel?

Comment: Singletons are closed, hence Borel.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** You can write a singleton as a countable intersection of intervals.

Comment: Do you think this ${r}= \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(r+1/n,r]$? Is this correct?

Comment: Try that with $r-1/n$ and it will be.

Comment: Yes, of course. My miстаке. Тhank you.